# Who/What am I talking about?

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

> Don't spit on me
>
> Judas already did
>
> At least you are not the devil
>
> But you are also not my hero
>
> I'm becoming invisible to you
>
> Are you sure you are not misunderstanding anger...
>
> ...with confusion?
>
> I'm my own master
>
> Drink some whiskey
>
> We are going to get justice!

I don't know if this is too hard, so here's a hint:

> Each phrase has a word that the answer is about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are talking about

> Metallica.
>  Each line refers to a song

Don't spit on me

> Spit out the bone

Judas already did

> Judas Kiss

At least you are not the devil

> Devil's Dance

But you are also not my hero

> Hero of the Day

I'm becoming invisible to you

> Invisible Kid

Are you sure you are not misunderstanding anger...

> St. Anger

...with confusion?

> Confusion

I'm my own master

> Master of Puppets

Drink some whiskey

> Whiskey in the Jar

We are going to get justice!

> And Justice for All

Comment: Whoa, that was quick, great job! :)

Comment: I was actually digging into a different direction first, and then I got to the last 3 lines and was like "WAIT A SECOND"

Comment: I was afraid of putting the lesser known songs and make the puzzle too hard...